# Network graph error: failed to validate StaticLayoutProvider(id='1058', ...).graph_layout:

Tags: python, networkx, bokeh

I managed to solve half of my issue so I modified this post, the only problem I encounter now is a error type that has no record to find a solution, if anyone know why this error happens and can give me some advice or some links lead my way to a solution, it will be appreciate.

My nodes are list of lists from Dataframe, my edges are from a list of tuples.

I know below error may due to my nodes and edges involved in G=nx.Graph(),
but they run well if I just need a static plot, but no idea how to modify it when I need a dynamic graph.

Below is part of my code:

```
    ...
    nodelist = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, N, O, P, Q, R]
    #create empty graph
    G = nx.Graph()
    
    node_list = []
    for sublist in nodelist:
        for item in sublist:
            node_list.append(item)
    for i in node_list:
        G.add_node(i)  
    
    G.nodes()
    
    edges = set(AB+BC+CN+NE+ED+DO+OP+PQ+QH+HG+GF+FR+BE+HR)
    # edges
    
    G.add_edges_from(edges)
    
    pos = nx.fruchterman_reingold_layout(G, scale=4)
    
    #nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, nodelist=nodelist[0], with_labels=False, node_size=10, node_color='#FF0000', font_size=5, width=2)
    ...
    plot = Plot(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,x_range=Range1d(-1.1, 1.1), y_range=Range1d(-1.1, 1.1))
        
    title = "track-dynamic graph"
        
    HOVER_TOOLTIPS = [("a", "@index"), ("b", "@type")]
        
    plot = figure(tooltips = HOVER_TOOLTIPS, tools="pan,wheel_zoom,save,reset", active_scroll='wheel_zoom',x_range=Range1d(-10.1, 10.1), y_range=Range1d(-10.1, 10.1), title=title)
        
    network_graph = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, scale=10, center=(0, 0))
    
    network_graph.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=3, fill_color='blue')
        
    network_graph.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_alpha=0.5, line_width=1)
        
    plot.renderers.append(network_graph)
        
    show(plot)
```

Above bokeh code gives me below error:

> ValueError: failed to validate StaticLayoutProvider(id='1058', ...).graph_layout: expected an element of Dict(Either(String, Int), Seq(Any)), got {'6600d5067598ac904ac8e1ed3d3760c0': array([-1.67995763,  3.53275585]), 'd151da7d698cd5a6f6957ca77549ebbe': array([-5.69608212,  0.91764808])...

Comment: Seems like the versions of Bokeh and networkx you have installed are incompatible. What are they? (You should always state relevant version information on every single question.)

Comment: The Bokeh version did not make it into your comment, and as I mentioned the networkx version is important and relevant as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, bokeh: 2.3.1, networkx :  2.5.1, sorry ya, not so familiar with the reply fuction so didn't finish my typing previously

Answer (score 0):

You are calling [`from_networkx`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html?highlight=from_networkx#bokeh.plotting.graph.from_networkx) without suplying all the required parameters. You must supply the `layout_function` parameter, which controls what kind of layout you want. You can pass any of the layout functions [built in to networkx](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/drawing.html#module-networkx.drawing.layout). Supplying this required paramater is demonstrated explicitly in the Bokeh [user's guide for networkx integration](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html#networkx-integration), e.g.

```py
import networkx as nx

graph = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, ...) # use spring_layout
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, @bigreddot, I added the layout_function, but got a new kind of error.....ValueError: failed to validate StaticLayoutProvider(id='1058', ...).graph_layout: expected an element of Dict(Either(String, Int), Seq(Any)), got {'6600d5067598ac904ac8e1ed3d3760c0': array([-1.67995763,  3.53275585]), 'd151da7d698cd5a6f6957ca77549ebbe': array([-5.69608212,  0.91764808]), ....)

Comment: I can't speculate further without a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to actually run and investigate.

Comment: @Alicia, I got the same error! How did you solve it?

Comment: @errenmike1806 please help others help you, by opening a question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The accepted solution here worked for me! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74903682/failed-to-validate-staticlayoutproviderid-p1075-expected-an-element-of-di

Answer (score 0):

This's post to reproduce problem

Had the same problem on python 3.9.14 and bokeh 3.1.0

```
ValueError: failed to validate StaticLayoutProvider(id='p1076', ...).graph_layout: expected an element of Dict(Int, Seq(Any)), got {'Aemon': array([-0.31649242,  2.58870237]), 'Grenn': array([-0.74669326,  4.67785828]), 'Samwell': array([-2.08387338,  4.10110813]), 'Doran': array([4.01849557, 1.36418261]), 'Walton': array([-2.55845497, -4.56622778])}
```

To reproduce problem:

1. download jupyter notebook from
   https://github.com/melaniewalsh/Intro-Cultural-Analytics/blob/master/book/06-Network-Analysis/02-Making-Network-Viz-with-Bokeh.ipynb
2. download data from https://github.com/melaniewalsh/Intro-Cultural-Analytics/blob/master/book/data/got-edges.csv
3. run notebook

p.s. haven't enough reputation to post it as comment to @bigreddot message.

Comment: https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/calling-from-networkx-using-a-graph-with-string-nodes/9719
- "Bokeh graph renderers currently expect integer node indices to be used."