# failed to validate StaticLayoutProvider(id='p1075' ... expected an element of Dict(Int, Seq(Any)), got {'A': array([-7.94707039, 3.45521447]),

Tags: pandas, networkx, bokeh

I am trying to draw network graphs following [from this example](https://melaniewalsh.github.io/Intro-Cultural-Analytics/06-Network-Analysis/02-Making-Network-Viz-with-Bokeh.html).

Below is what I am trying to do.

```
`data = {
    'source': ['A', 'C', 'B', 'F', 'G'],
    'target': ['B', 'D', 'E', 'C', 'E'],
    'weight': [5, 3, 10, 4, 7]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
G = networkx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'source', 'target', 'weight')
# Choose a title!
title = 'Graph Network'

# Establish which categories will appear when hovering over each node
HOVER_TOOLTIPS = [("Character", "@index")]
# Create a plot — set dimensions, toolbar, and title
plot = figure(tooltips=HOVER_TOOLTIPS,
              tools="pan,wheel_zoom,save,reset", active_scroll='wheel_zoom',
              x_range=Range1d(-10.1, 10.1), y_range=Range1d(-10.1, 10.1), title=title)

network_graph = from_networkx(G, networkx.spring_layout, scale=10, center=(0, 0))

# Set node size and color
network_graph.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=15, fill_color='skyblue')

# Set edge opacity and width
network_graph.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_alpha=0.5, line_width=1)

# Add network graph to the plot
plot.renderers.append(network_graph)

return plot`
```

The error I get is as below;

```
failed to validate StaticLayoutProvider(id='p1075', ...).graph_layout: expected an 
element of Dict(Int, Seq(Any)), got {'A': array([-7.94707039,  3.45521447]), 'B': 
array([-6.60505319,  4.31869148]), 'C': array([ 8.38746457, -6.26423001]), 'D': 
array([ 6.7178286 , -6.63523276]), 'E': array([-5.66671517,  5.25260372]), 'F': 
array([10.        , -6.53836091]), 'G': array([-4.88645443,  6.41131401])}
```

The error is self-explanatory. The engine expects an integer as a key, but I pass a String into it.

This error is similar to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67310693/network-graph-error-failed-to-validate-staticlayoutproviderid-1058-gra)

However in this case, the error specifies `expected an element of Dict(Either(String, Int), Seq(Any))` that both String and Int are allowed. While in my case, the error specifies that only ints are allowed.

And indeed if I simulate the source and target as integers, the graph is drawn successfully.

If it helps, I am using `networkx~=2.8.8` and `bokeh==3.0.3`.

Can anyone help me identify what I am doing wrong.

Comment: This looks like a regression. I was running your example with bokeh 2.4.3 without problems. Maybe it is worth to open an [issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) on GitHub. As long as only integers are supported, you can run `df.source=df.source.apply(ord)` etc.

Comment: FYI, bokeh has a nice example for [networkx](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/topics/graph/from_networkx.html).

Comment: Thanks @mosc9575, changing bokeh to 2.4.3 does not raise the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is still an open bug in https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/12651

My solution is to create new Graph H, and relabel it with integer.

```
mapping = dict((n, i) for i, n in enumerate(G.nodes))
H = networkx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping)
```

Then draw from the graph H.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using BokehJS 3.2.1. My nodes are strings attached using add_edge and

```
graph = from_networkx(nxg, nx.spring_layout)
```

fails with

```
ValueError: failed to validate StaticLayoutProvider(id='p1141', ...).graph_layout: expected an element of Dict(Int, Seq(Any)), got ...
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew Spruce this is more of a comment/question than an answer. Please follow guidelines.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34802585)